# Gaussian as Markov kernels

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-process, marginal-distribution

Let the one-step transition dynamics of a system be given as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t] = N(f_\theta(X_t), I)
\end{equation*}
that is the Normal with mean a function of $X_t$ paramterized by $\theta$. My question is what would be $$\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_t] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_{t+1}]\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t]dX_{t+1}?$$

Is there a simple closed form solution for a general $f_\theta$? That is would $\mathbf{P}[X_{t+2} | X_t]$ be a Normal Distribution?  What if the one step transition is given as a linear function e.g,

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P}[X_{t+1} | X_t] = N(AX_t+b, I) ?
\end{equation*}
What would the mean and variance be if it is a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question around a general $f_\theta$, I do not believe this has a close formed solution as integration of an arbitrary function is already not possible in closed form.

```
import torch as t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_t = t.tensor(100)
n = 100000
def f(x):
  value = 1000*(x.cos())
  return value

x_t1_samples = t.randn(n) + f(x_t)
new_mean = f(x_t1_samples)
plt.hist(new_mean + t.randn(n), bins=1000)
```

Running a quick example case with a funky f, we can see that the resulting histogram is non-normal:

[image]

The special linear case should be solvable and Gaussian, I suggest working from the Gaussian form $e^{-(x - \mu)^2}$ combining terms where possible in the integration and trying to convert it to something new resembling a Gaussian form.